# OpenCV webcam MJPG low FPS

Tags: c++, opencv

The problem is that I am keep getting low FPS from Logitech C270 webcam capture in OpenCV3. 
Things i've tried are described in code comments

```
Mat frame;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    // i've tried it this way
//int apiBackend = cv::CAP_DSHOW;
//cv::VideoCapture cap(0+apiBackend);

//and tis way
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.open(0);

cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC ,cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G') );

//cap.set(CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE , 1); //changing this gives no result
//cap.set(CAP_PROP_GAIN , 10);    // same with this

cap.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 100);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

while(1)
{
    float e1 = cv::getTickCount();

    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

    imshow("frame", frame);

    float e2 = cv::getTickCount();
    float t = (e2 - e1)/cv::getTickFrequency();
    float fps = 1.0 / t;
    std::cout << fps << std::endl;

    if(waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Changing CAP_PROP_FPS to 5 works, and FPS drops ok.

Playing with resolution didn't help: from 320*240 to 1280*720 i keep getting about 16 FPS.

Webcam drivers are latest.
Am i missing something?

Comment: Is your subject well illuminated? Exposure time gives you the upper limit of the frame rate you can get, so if the camera has auto-exposure enabled (which it likely does) it might be trying to compensate for a dark environment.

Comment: Try setting the height and width **before** setting the framerate.

Comment: @DanMašek, i've tried it in the dark room and fps didn't change, same thing with all the lights on. so i guess auto exposure is disabled

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks, tried it, but fps is solid 17 unfortunately

Comment: Perhap std:cout is the most costly operation in your while loop, try to remove it and calculate the fps by using a long bench mark time.

Comment: @TungLeThanh It can be slowish, but not on the order of many milliseconds per frame just to display a number. If anything, I'd drop the `imshow`/`waitKey`, but even those shouldn't have so much overhead at 320x240 on any reasonable hardware...

Comment: @ub0baa Hmm. What sort of hardware is this running on? What about the connection -- I'd try different ports to make sure you're not getting bandwidth limited due to some other device on the same host controller, or even being on a lower quality controller. Can some other software on the same machine get better framerate? Can you try reproduce the issue on different machine?

Comment: Did you try CAP_DSHOW as option passed to open() function ? I dont see it in your commented code.

Comment: not using MJPG will give higher fps?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks fo suggestions everybody!
Looks like the answer is camera-specific: i had to install Logitech Webcam Software and disable RightLight feature, now FPS is about 30.
Maybe there is some way to disable RightLight from OpenCV using cap.set(...), but this is subject for further investigation.